# Show that the equation for $\nabla F$ yields the same result for all Cartesian coordinate systems

Tags: multivariable-calculus

We know that any 2 Cartesian coordinate systems are related by a rotation and a translation:

$x'=a+x\cos\alpha-y\sin\alpha$

$y'=b+x\sin\alpha+y\cos\alpha$

Consider the equation

$\nabla F = \frac{\partial F}{\partial x}i + \frac{\partial F}{\partial y}j$

The goal is to show that this equation yields the same results under the coordinate change above.

My approach was to compute $\nabla F'$, where

$F'(x', y')=F(a+x\cos\alpha-y\sin\alpha, b+x\sin\alpha+y\cos\alpha)$

Computing the partial derivatives of $F'$, I got:

$\frac{\partial F'}{\partial x'} = \frac{\partial F(a+x\cos\alpha-y\sin\alpha, b+x\sin\alpha+y\cos\alpha)}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial F}{\partial x}\cos\alpha i + \frac{\partial F}{\partial y}\sin\alpha j$

$\frac{\partial F'}{\partial y'} = \frac{\partial F(a+x\cos\alpha-y\sin\alpha, b+x\sin\alpha+y\cos\alpha)}{\partial y} = -\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}\sin\alpha i + \frac{\partial F}{\partial y}\cos\alpha j$

Summing them, I got

$\nabla F' = \frac{\partial F}{\partial x}(-\sin\alpha + \cos\alpha)i + \frac{\partial F}{\partial y}(\cos\alpha+\sin\alpha)j$

The new basis $i', j'$, as derived from the original transformation, is:

$i'=\cos\alpha i + \sin\alpha j$

$j'=-\sin\alpha i + \cos\alpha j$

I was hoping I could replace the trigonometric sums in the expression for $\nabla F'$ by $i',j'$. They *look* similar, but it seems like I am missing something.

For reference, this is the Exercise 1.4 from the book *Introduction to Tensor Analysis and the Calculus of Moving Surfaces*.

Comment: Could you place a backslash in front of all of your trig syntax?

Comment: @Winther After looking a bit more at the problem, and following your advice, I am still stuck on small detail: I am not sure how to substitute $i'$ and $j'$ in the expression for $\nabla F'$.

Comment: @Kevin Done. Thanks for the tip, didn't know about that.

Comment: @Paul92 No worries. Cheers

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to do mathematically. Are you trying to prove that $\nabla F = \nabla F'$ at each point?

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг Yes. Basically to show that the gradient does not change if the coordinate system is translated and/or rotated.

Comment: That has been done below, then!

Answer (score 3):

The derivatives must be taken w.r.t. the new coordinates $x'$, $y'$. First note that $\frac{\partial}{\partial x'}$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial y'}$ are *not* equal to $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$. Also note that your expression for $\frac{\partial F'}{\partial x'}$, etc. cannot be correct, because the left hand side is a number and the right hand side a vector.

By the chain rule we have
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x} &= \frac{\partial x'}{\partial x}\frac{\partial}{\partial x'} + \frac{\partial y'}{\partial x}\frac{\partial}{\partial y'} =
\phantom{-}\cos\alpha\frac{\partial}{\partial x'} + \sin\alpha\frac{\partial}{\partial y'} \\
%
\frac{\partial}{\partial y} &= \frac{\partial x'}{\partial y}\frac{\partial}{\partial x'} + \frac{\partial y'}{\partial y}\frac{\partial}{\partial y'} =
-\sin\alpha\frac{\partial}{\partial x'} + \cos\alpha\frac{\partial}{\partial y'}.
\tag{1}
\end{align}
$$
So
$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x'} &=
\cos\alpha\frac{\partial}{\partial x} - \sin\alpha\frac{\partial}{\partial y} \\
%
\frac{\partial}{\partial y'} &=
\sin\alpha\frac{\partial}{\partial x} + \cos\alpha\frac{\partial}{\partial y}.
\tag{2}
\end{align*} 
$$

Now we can calculate $\frac{\partial F'}{\partial x'}$; the calculation for $\frac{\partial F'}{\partial y'}$ is very similar.
$$
\begin{align*}
 \frac{\partial F'}{\partial x'} &= \cos\alpha \frac{\partial F'}{\partial x} - \sin \alpha \frac{\partial F'}{\partial y} \\
&=\cos\alpha \left( \cos\alpha \frac{\partial F}{\partial x} + \sin \alpha \frac{\partial F}{\partial y'}\right) - \sin \alpha\left(-\sin\alpha \frac{\partial F}{\partial x} +\cos \alpha \frac{\partial F}{\partial y'}\right)\\
&= (\cos^2\alpha + \sin^2\alpha) \frac{\partial F}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial F}{\partial x}.
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: Notice that according to @Ernie060's computation 
$$ \nabla F' = (\frac{\partial F'}{\partial x'} , \frac{\partial F'}{\partial y'}) $$ in the old system is just $(\partial_xF',\partial_uF')$ rotated by angle $\alpha$. To rewrite any vector in the new system you must rotate it by inverse of the rotation used to obtain the new system, (draw a picture to see!) so this makes $\nabla F' = 1 \partial_{x'} F' + 1 \partial_{y'}F'$ in the $x',y'$ coordinate.

Comment: Ernie, how did you conclude from the above results that $$\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x'} &=
\cos\alpha\frac{\partial}{\partial x} - \sin\alpha\frac{\partial}{\partial y} \\
\frac{\partial}{\partial y'} &=
\sin\alpha\frac{\partial}{\partial x} + \cos\alpha\frac{\partial}{\partial y}.
\end{align*}$$?

Comment: @The Pointer The first pair of equations can be written as
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \\ \frac{\partial}{\partial y} 
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos \alpha & \sin\alpha \\ -\sin\alpha & \cos \alpha
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x'} \\ \frac{\partial}{\partial y'} 
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
In order to get the second pair of equations, multiply both sides with the inverse of the rotation matrix. And the inverse of a rotation matrix is easy to get: just replace the angle $\alpha$ with $-\alpha$.

Comment: @Ernie060 But none of those are the same as $$\begin{align*} \frac{\partial}{\partial x'} &= \cos\alpha\frac{\partial}{\partial x} - \sin\alpha\frac{\partial}{\partial y} \\ \frac{\partial}{\partial y'} &= \sin\alpha\frac{\partial}{\partial x} + \cos\alpha\frac{\partial}{\partial y}. \end{align*}$$? Or perhaps I'm misunderstanding the reasoning you're going through here.

Comment: @The Pointer The first pair of equations (the ones I wrote in my previous comment, and I labeled them (1) in my answer) express $\partial/\partial x$ and $\partial/\partial y$ in terms of $\partial/\partial x'$ and $\partial y'$. If we want to find expressions for $\partial/\partial x'$ and $\partial y'$ (the equations (2)) we can solve the linear system of equations (1). And this is done by multiplying both sides with the inverse rotation matrix. Expanding that result will give you (2).